# UnicodeDecodeError in socket.sendall with Django

Tags: python, django, sockets

I have following piece of code in client program which connects with server and sends a message to the server:

msg = struct.pack('!HH', 1, 152)

sock.sendall(msg + astr) # Here astr is an ascii string with length 148

When I run the client program from command line, it works fine. But when the program is invoked from Django, I get following error on the sock.sendall function line:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)

I searched for possible solutions for this and tried different solutions like setting LANG variable, using msg.encode('utf-8') but nothing worked.

Is it something to do with Django settings because it works fine when I invoke the program from shell.

Comment: maybe it's logged by django?

Answer (score 1):

0x98 is not a valid ASCII character. Where does that character come from?

As a workaround, try using 'latin1' codec. (Latin-1 has a valid code point for each of the 256 possible byte values so, even though the text you send may not make sense at the far end, you can successfully encode and decode all byte values using it.)

Something like this:

```
sock.sendall(msg + astr.encode('latin1'))
```

More generally, you'll need to discover where the 0x98 character comes from and determine what is the proper codec to use in transmitting it to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The value 0x98 is nothing but the length of the string. Please note that the first statement (struct.pack('!HH', 1, 152)) results into following hex byte sequence: 00 01 00 98